# Multiple Runnable in one Handler to manage animations

Tags: android, multithreading, android-animation, runnable, android-handler

I've three runnables for three animations and I want to manage this in a good way to avoid any performance issue.

From what I could read create one handler and send then a different message for different operation could be a solution : `handler.sendEmptyMessage(msg)`

Basically in my code I click on one button which should trigger my 3 animations through a new Handler here

*Solution one (S1) onClick button listener :*

```
    Handler h = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            if (msg.what == 1) {
                postDelayed(rColumnOne, mSpeedc1);
            } else if (msg.what == 2) {
                postDelayed( rColumnTwo, mSpeedc1);
            } else if (msg.what == 3) {
                postDelayed( rColumnThree, mSpeedc1);
            }
        }
    };

    h.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    h.sendEmptyMessage(2);
    h.sendEmptyMessage(3);
```

*Solution two (S2) onClick button listener :*

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed( rColumnOne, mSpeedc1);
handler.postDelayed( rColumnTwo, mSpeedc2);
handler.postDelayed( rColumnThree, mSpeedc3);
```

The S1 & S2 are working both of my animations are triggered. But it's seems to be a bit slow sometimes. Most of the time it's okay but sometimes it's not smooth or not all the animations are triggered.

It could be maybe because I don't destroy the runnable/handler at the end but not sure if it's needed in that case. *What would be the best practice in that case ? Is there a solution better than the other ?*

Comment: the best practice? use a `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`

Comment: @pskink I'm going to look at these, thank you. I m just using a classic Animation object that I set to 3 viewFlippers with a translation to simulate a vertical scroll as a slot machine.

Comment: in that case you can even use `ViewPropertyAnimator` and one of `translation*` method